# No compiler warning when there's a comma instead of a semicolon in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-warnings, comma-operator

Why doesn't gcc give any warnings about this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printDigits(int *arr, int arrsize);

int main() {
    int number[] = { 1, 7, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2 };
    size_t arraysize = (sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]));

    printDigits(number, arraysize);

    return 0;
}

void printDigits(int *arr, int arrsize) {
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i<arrsize, i++;) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Specifically about the for loop in printDigits function. It's:
`for(i=0; i<arrsize, i++;)`
while it really should be `for(i=0; i<arrsize; i++)`

Gcc didn't give me any warnings and it took me a while to figure out why doesn't the array print out.

Comment: GCC 10.2 [does](https://godbolt.org/z/6jsxMv) give a warning, “left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]”. Did you turn warnings on with `-Wall` or another switch that includes `-Wunused-value`? What version of GCC are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a warning. `i<arrsize` is computed but then discarded, so gcc warns:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

(Which is enabled by `-Wall`)

Comment: So the question becomes: why does **gcc** not have `-Wall` turned on by default?

Comment: @chqrlie. Because spiritual children of Unix work on the principle that you are responsible for your own setup?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yes and no: `rm -r /` does ask if you really mean it :)

Comment: @chqrlie It doesn't, when ran from a script. And I think also in interactive mode it didn't ask from the beginning

Comment: @Uroc327: indeed this extra sanity check was added at some point... Which supports my point: it is high time the default warning level should be increase in gcc. Backward compatibility would be preserved if this was only changed if called from an interactive shell.

Comment: @chqrlie. It only does that if you alias it as far as I know. Most distros alias it that way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: very good suggestion. `alias gcc='gcc -Wall'` does the job. I have not seen distros with this in the global shell profile, but it is an acceptable solution. Where have you seen that?

Comment: @chqrlie. I was referring to rm. I've never seen the gcc alias, but it's a good solution for when you want something quick on the command line in the same spirit.

Answer (score 3):

This for loop

```
for(i=0; i<arrsize, i++;){
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

is a valid C construction. In the condition of the loop there is used the comma operator

```
i<arrsize, i++
```

the value of which is the value of its second operand. So the body of the loop will not be executed because the value of the expression `i++` is 0 (that is value of the variable `i` before its increment).

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
> has its type and value

Pay attention to that any expression in the for loop may be omitted. For example you can even write like

```
for ( ; ; )
{
    //...
}
```

Also you should at least change the type of the second function parameter from `int` to `size_t`  because you are passing an argument of the type `size_t`.

The function should be declared like

```
void printDigits( const int *arr, size_t arrsize );
```

Answer (score -2):

It is a valid C. This for loop will execute until `i` is non zero